# return item with chaining pattern javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, chaining

I'm developing a small library to learn more about javascript

I am using a chaining pattern:

```
(function(window) {
    var myLibrary = function(iD) {
        var e = document.getElementById(iD),
            methods = {
                one: function(val) {
                    e.innerHTML = val;
                    return this; // maintain chainability
                },
                two: function(val) {
                    alert(val);
                    return this; // maintain chainability
                }
            };
        return methods;
    };
    window.myLibrary = myLibrary;
})(window);
```

chaining is fine, but I can not use an internal property of JavaScript. for example

```
myLibrary("ID").length
```

any idea to return the item?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `.length` to represent? You're always retrieving **one** (or zero) element (by `id`)...so it wouldn't make sense to represent the number of elements found (like how jQuery does it).

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but here's more or less how I'd set up this "library": http://jsfiddle.net/mq38W/1/ (I'd say it's somewhat close to how jQuery handles things, although there are obviously many things missing, as well as not being structured exactly the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`length` properties are generally associated with ordered collections like `String`s and `Array`s. `methods`, as an `Object`, is neither.

So, if you want it to have a `length`, you have to give it one:

```
methods = {
    length: e == null ? 0 : 1,

    // ...
};
```

```
myLibrary('ID').length
```

Or, define a method that `return`s something other than `this` that would have a `length` itself:

```
methods = {
    html: function () {
        return e.innerHTML;
    },

    // ...
};
```

```
myLibrary('ID').html().length
```

Comment: i think she wants to get the number of elements with length which is always 1/0

Comment: @Ankit The 1st snippet demonstrates that, to the limits of `getElementById()` -- `e == null ? 0 : 1`.

Comment: +1yeah you are right however i am not liking the way on which this library is getting built

Comment: confused me, put documen.getElementById by document.getElmentsByTagName